# Reinitialize or reset datepiker limits

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

Greatings
i have a couple of datepicker inputs, the first sets the limits for the second, but if the user trys to select an other initial date the limits of the second input stays the same as the first time it was selected.
how could i reset the datepickers every time i select an other sdate

```js
//
function load_pmForm(){
    $("#main_rcol").hide().load('frontend/incs/assets.php #p_milestones', function(){
        var limit1 =jQuery.data( document.body,"pd1");
        var limit2 =jQuery.data( document.body,"pd2");
        $("#pm_sdate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
            minDate: limit1,
            maxDate: limit2,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                $("#pm_edate").datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                     minDate: dateText,
                     maxDate: limit2
                });
            }
        });
    }).fadeIn('500'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to influence one datepicker by other, you can do this e.g. this way. Here are datepickers `date_from` and `date_to`

```
    $("#date_from").datepicker({
        ...
        onSelect: function () {
            date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            $("#date_to").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
            $(this).change();
        }
    });

    $("#date_to").datepicker({
        ...
        onSelect: function () {
            date = $(this).datepicker("getDate");
            date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1);
            $("#date_from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
            $(this).change();
        }
    });
```

In your case you need also add to your code `$(this).change();`

```
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#pm_edate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                 minDate: dateText,
                 maxDate: limit2
            });
>>>>        $(this).change();      <<<<
        }
```